# Powershell script to filter objects only with match condition

Tags: powershell, object, filter, match

How we can filter objects from xml file with match condition only and save it to new file.

Like we want to display address objects which are not being used under any rules or groups.

Like used objects will be under member syntax however unused objects will not be under member bracket.
object-name

Comment: Your question is very vague - can you share a sample input file, and some expected output?

Comment: Please create an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that the question is clear.